# Why is the activity overview partially transparent?

Tags: support

When I hover over my user name, the activity overview is partially transparent and unreadable in Opera 11.51 on Windows XP. It looks fine in Chrome.

I know it was working earlier this afternoon.

[image: Transparent activity overview]

Comment: I cannot reproduce it on Opera 11.51 running on Mac OS X 10.7.1. I even tried enabling "Opera Turbo," but I didn't notice this issue.

Comment: I am on Windows, I tried already to restart my Opera, but no change. I am always using Opera and thats the first time I see this.

Comment: Can't reproduce this either

Comment: Maybe its on my side, I recognized I have problems on some other sides too.

Answer (score 2):

So I found the problem.

It seems that I activated a Opera setting accidentally in "View - Style". Deactivating everything and SO looks again fine.